# C# regex help - validating input

Tags: c#, regex

I need to validate that the user entered text in the format:

```
####-#####-####-###
```

Can I do this using Regex.Match?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
private static readonly Regex _validator = 
    new Regex(@"^\d{4}-\d{5}-\d{4}-\d{3}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
private static bool ValidateInput(string input)
{
    input = (input ?? string.Empty);
    if (input.Length != 19)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return _validator.IsMatch(input);
}
```

Comment: Isn't that only for numbers? It is true that the question does not specify exactly what "text" is.

Comment: @Liviu - I usually interpret **#** as a numeric placeholder.

Comment: why go through the trouble of checking the length and and having multiple returns, is the precompiled regex operation so expensive that it's not worth doing?  I would just let it fail the regex and make the method simpler.  I do however like that you are using \d instead of [0-9]

Comment: @dstarh - I don't consider checking the length to be much trouble. It is such an easy way to validate the input. In a high throughput process it can make a difference in performance as well. *(Not much I admit.)*

Comment: Should those literal `-` characters, code point 45 HYPHEN-MINUS, be better written as `\p{Pd}` for any sort of dash punctuation?  And if you wanted them to be all of the same sort, you could write `^\d{4}(\p{Pd})\d{5}\1\d{4}\p{Pd}\1\d{3}$`.

Comment: @tchrist - I believe that if you had to escape the hyphen-minus outside of a character class I would use a Unicode escape sequence `\u002d`.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: It’s not a matter of escaping HYPHEN-MINUS characters; it’s about accepting any dash character there. BTW, that `\u002d` scares me into thinking that C♯ may share Java’s stupid UTF-16 design errors for astral code points. Would you happen to know whether it does?

Comment: @tchrist - After a bit of research it seems you are correct although some might call it a calculated design decision rather than stupidity.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: I’d call it a *mis*calculated decision, or maybe a design blunder. People jumped on the UCS-2 bandwagon far too fast, locking them into a non-extensible system. Having partial Unicode support is even worse than not having any, because you never know when your code is going to break.